# What is the best way to write a File given a Path instance?

Tags: rust, path, io

If you have an instance of `std::path::Path` and want to write a text File to that path, what is the best way? I can call `.display()` to get a string and then use File I/O methods that take strings as file names, but is there a preferred way that involves something related to `Path`, `PathBuf`, etc? The `.display()` method is said to be lossy due to encoding issues so I would prefer a means that did not sacrifice generality.

Comment: I'm confused. What does it mean to "have an instance of `std::path::Path`"? Which "File I/O methods" "take strings as file names"? (`File::open`, `File::create`, `std::fs::write` all take `<P: AsRef<Path>>`.) Why is `display` relevant?

Comment: All file-related APIs accept `Path`s, so if you have one, you should be all set. For example: `let out = BufWriter::new(File::create(your_path)?); ...` or `std::fs::write(your_path, b"some data here")?`.

Comment: @trentcl - It is not you who are confused, but me. All the examples I saw on the web and in documentation employed strings as file names. Only by looking at the actual method signatures does it become clear that Paths are the main operands. Yes, it is possible to spend hours searching for an example and still not notice that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::fs::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.write.html). The function has following signature, so it will work with `Path` objects too.

```
pub fn write<P: AsRef<Path>, C: AsRef<[u8]>>(path: P, contents: C) -> Result<()>
```

Comment: Thanks! All the Web examples I saw using the write method gave &str values for the path, so I assumed it only took strings.

Comment: @PaulChernoch The methods accept strings _for convenience_, but paths are actually their primary interface.